# Flutter appinioswiper swipe indicator

Tags: flutter, dart, tinder

Is it possible to give the appinioswiper cards two indicators, so that if the user swipes to the left there will slowly appear a text on the left of the card, the more the user swipes to the left. The text will say 'dislike' so the user knows what he is doing by swiping to the left. Tinder has something like that as an example.

[Heres a link to the library with an example](https://pub.dev/packages/appinio_swiper)

Comment: I'm just about to implement the exact same thing. You'll want to hook into the `onSwiping` event for that.